# $x^3-3x+1=0$ has three real roots $x_{1}\;x_{2}\;,x_{3}$. Then what is the value of $\{x_{1}\}+\{x_{2}\}+\{x_{3}\}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots

> If the equation $x^3-3x+1=0$ has three real roots $x_{1}\;x_{2}\;,x_{3}\;,$ Where $x_{1}<x_{2}<x_{3}$.
>
> Then the value of $\{x_{1}\}+\{x_{2}\}+\{x_{3}\} = \;,$ Where $\{x\}$ Represent fractional part of $x.$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $f(x) = x^3-3x+1\;,$ Then Using Second Derivative Test, We get

$f'(x) = 3x^2-3$ and $f''(x) = 6x\;,$ Now for $\max$ and $\min\;,$ Put $f'(x) =0\;,$ So we get

$3x^2-3=0\Rightarrow x = \pm 1.$ Now $f''(1) = 6>0$

So $x=1$ is a Point of $\min$ and $f''(-1) = -6<0$

So $x=-1$ is a Point of $\max.$

And Rough graph of $f(x) = x^3-3x+1$ is Like

[image]

So we get $-2<x_{1}<-1$ and $0<x_{2}<1$ and $1<x_{3}<2$

So $\lfloor x_{1}\rfloor = -2$ and $\lfloor x_{2}\rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor x_{3}\rfloor = 1$

Now I did not Understand How can I calculate value of fractional part

Help me, Thanks

Comment: $x=-1$ is the maxima and $x=1$ is the minima.

Comment: @Aniket: ‘maxima’ and ‘minima’  are plural forms in Latin.

Comment: What is the value of the fractional part for negative numbers?  There are various conventions.  For instance, is tha fractional part of `-1.4` equal to `-0.4` or `+0.6`?

Comment: The values of $x$ are 

$$2\cos80^\circ,2\cos40^\circ,2\cos160^\circ=-2\cos20^\circ$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$
and that
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=0.$$

Comment: Why $x_1+x_2+x_+3=0$ ?

Comment: @stity: Because of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: ho yes forgot this on, than you !

Answer (score 2):

$\left\{x_1\right\}+\left\{x_2\right\}+\left\{x_3\right\}=x_1+x_2+x_3-[x_1]-[x_2]-[x_3]=0-(-2+0+1)=1$